# QGIS Layout: Filter Nth Row in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, expression, feature-filter

I have an attribute table in a Qgis Layout and only want to see the first line.

Can I do that?

It's a workaround for overlapping labels.

I want an attribute table with the 1. Line, then a table with the 2. line... and so on
Only features intersecting the atlas are shown.
Most of the time it's not more than 1 to 10 at the same time.
I tried various things with arrays in the filter expression but can not find a solution.

In the "Filter with" expression I probably need something like "the first result of the **array that is intersecting the atlas**" or something like that!

[image]

Comment: Can't you simply set the no. of maximum rows from 20 (see your screenshot) to 1?

Comment: If you use the same layer for atlas-control and attribute table, you may use `@atlas_pagename = "attribute atlas page is derived from"` as filter expression.

Comment: set the 'Maximum rows' to 1 (@Babel's comment above) and activate the checkbox 'Show only features visible within the map'

Comment: Thanks guys,
setting the max rows to 1 would only return the first result, but I also need those other rows, each row in a seperate attribute table. I think I have to go with the labels. I just thought I could save some time somehow and avoid placing hundreds of lables manually. I hope some day, labels won't overlap each other anymore automatically. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello @Samurai2020, I have made a proposal, if it work for you can mark it as a solution, if not you can give more information to your question i could adapt answer to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions that could work :

1. if your cell height don't vary too much.
2. if your label need to appear only in one atlaspage, or in all atlaspage but not on two atlaspages.

You still use the table but make multiple "cadre" (sorry I don't know the English name, it is just above `position and size`). This is normally used when you have a table split in different pages, but you could use it for your project.

In my screen capture you see my original table on the left side, and in right side you see the table divided in *cadre*. You see that below the 5th cell there is an empty *cadre* (5 *cadre* comes from max number of lines). Each *cadre* is an object of your print composer, and it will fit as many rows as possible. You may have trouble to found the right dimension to get only one cell each time.

[image: normal table and table divided by cell]

---

Another workaround would be to use labels that have are filtered to be shown only for an atlas page. In the layer containing the label you want to show you add an integer field `atlas_id`. You fill it with the atlas fid of the page you want it to appear on OR you live it NULL for labels you want to show on every atlas page.

Here is an example of the filter you may set to show or not label base on current atlas feature.

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'fid') =  "atlas_id"  OR  "atlas_id" is null
```